# How to find the cause of a segment fault？

Tags: linux, gcc, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, coredump

I write an openssl engine, and everything seems to works correctly when it's running. But an segment fault happened when the program exit:

```
$ ./output/bin/async_test
1..1
PASS
[1]    24048 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./output/bin/async_test


# root @ localhost in /home/usr2/git/tmp2/build on git:702a8b8 x [16:35:22] C:139
$ gdb ./output/bin/async_test core.24048
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-120.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/usr2/git/tmp2/build/output/bin/async_test...done.
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 24048]
[New LWP 24049]
warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x826650 != 0xfbad2887
warning: Corrupted shared library list: 0x826650 != 0xfbad2887
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//lib64/libc-2.17.so.debug" does not match "/lib64/libc.so.6" (CRC mismatch).
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so.debug" does not match "/lib64/libc.so.6" (CRC mismatch).
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug//usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so.debug" does not match "/lib64/libc.so.6" (CRC mismatch).
warning: the debug information found in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64//libc-2.17.so.debug" does not match "/lib64/libc.so.6" (CRC mismatch).

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./output/bin/async_test'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f855b8ddfe8 in _dl_close_worker (map=map@entry=0x825b90) at dl-close.c:148
148       for (struct link_map *l = ns->_ns_loaded; l != NULL; l = l->l_next)
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-326.el7_9.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f855b8ddfe8 in _dl_close_worker (map=map@entry=0x825b90) at dl-close.c:148
#1  0x00007f855b8dedac in _dl_close (_map=0x825b90) at dl-close.c:776
#2  0x00007f855b8d87d4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x825b40, errstring=0x825b48, mallocedp=0x825b38, operate=0x7f855adca060 <dlclose_doit>, args=0x825b90)
    at dl-error.c:177
#3  0x00007f855adca5ad in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7f855adca060 <dlclose_doit>, args=0x825b90) at dlerror.c:163
#4  0x00007f855adca08f in __dlclose (handle=<optimized out>) at dlclose.c:47
#5  0x00007f855b4bbcf9 in dlfcn_unload (dso=0x8259c0) at crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:162
#6  0x00007f855b4bc59c in DSO_free (dso=0x8259c0) at crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:78
#7  0x00007f855b51684e in dynamic_data_ctx_free_func (parent=0x8256f0, ptr=0x825850, ad=0x825798, idx=1, argl=0, argp=0x0) at crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:140
#8  0x00007f855b543f37 in CRYPTO_free_ex_data (class_index=10, obj=0x8256f0, ad=0x825798) at crypto/ex_data.c:354
#9  0x00007f855b51814d in engine_free_util (e=0x8256f0, not_locked=0) at crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:95
#10 0x00007f855b518952 in engine_list_remove (e=0x8256f0) at crypto/engine/eng_list.c:125
#11 0x00007f855b518d66 in ENGINE_remove (e=0x8256f0) at crypto/engine/eng_list.c:239
#12 0x00007f855b518616 in engine_list_cleanup () at crypto/engine/eng_list.c:38
#13 0x00007f855b518308 in engine_cleanup_cb_free (item=0x80e4c0) at crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:162
#14 0x00007f855b5c4d9b in OPENSSL_sk_pop_free (st=0x80e490, func=0x7f855b5182f3 <engine_cleanup_cb_free>) at crypto/stack/stack.c:368
#15 0x00007f855b517e40 in sk_ENGINE_CLEANUP_ITEM_pop_free (sk=0x80e490, freefunc=0x7f855b5182f3 <engine_cleanup_cb_free>) at crypto/engine/eng_int.h:54
#16 0x00007f855b51834b in engine_cleanup_int () at crypto/engine/eng_lib.c:169
#17 0x00007f855b547d7a in OPENSSL_cleanup () at crypto/init.c:601
#18 0x00007f855b006ce9 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#19 0x00007f855b006d37 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#20 0x00007f855afef55c in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#21 0x00000000004023c9 in _start ()
(gdb)quit
```

I suspect that the memory is out of bounds, because the segment fault was happened at a function in libcrypto.so ,which is from openssl. I guess some memory of libcrypto was broken by my code. But I have no idea how to find the cause. so I googled and find a tool named ASAN or sanitize or something. Anyway, I tried it by adding some compiling options:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(qat ${crypto_path} libhct -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-recover=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
```

After that, I run the program, but it stopped at a line which is not an error:

```
build git:702a8b8 # ./output/bin/async_test
1..1
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==20978==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00c09fff8000 (pc 0x7f891c950e27 bp 0x62d000012530 sp 0x62d000011cc0 T0)
    #0 0x7f891c950e26 in AddressIsPoisoned ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_mapping.h:295
    #1 0x7f891c950e26 in QuickCheckForUnpoisonedRegion ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:40
    #2 0x7f891c950e26 in __interceptor_memset ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:451
    #3 0x7f8918453dad in cmd_passthru /home/usr2/git/tmp2/qat_crypto.c:126
    #4 0x7f89184ee4f9 in cipher_do_cipher /home/usr2/git/tmp2/qat_sm4.c:235
    #5 0x7f89187f069a in cipher_do_cipher /home/usr2/git/engine/e_qat.c:2335
    #6 0x7f891c57a7cc in evp_EncryptDecryptUpdate crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:333
    #7 0x7f891c57aa17 in EVP_EncryptUpdate crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:385
    #8 0x402b2a in enc_sw_dec /home/usr2/tmp2/async_test.c:95
    #9 0x7f891c485bfc in async_start_func crypto/async/async.c:152
    #10 0x7f891c05718f  (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x4818f)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_mapping.h:295 in AddressIsPoisoned
==20978==ABORTING
build git:702a8b8 #
```

So I tried to add the funciton "cmd_passthru" (which is written by myself and leads to the hault above) to the blacklist by add attribute "no_sanitize_address" at the head of it:

```
#if defined(__clang__) || defined (__GNUC__)
# define ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS __attribute__((no_sanitize_address))
#else
# define ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS
#endif

ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS
int cmd_passthru(void *saddr,uint32_t slen,uint32_t first,uint32_t final)
{
...
}
```

But when I compiled the program again and run it, Asan reports the same error again:

```
build git:702a8b8 # ./output/bin/async_test
    1..1
    ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
    =================================================================
    ==20978==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x00c09fff8000 (pc 0x7f891c950e27 bp 0x62d000012530 sp 0x62d000011cc0 T0)
        #0 0x7f891c950e26 in AddressIsPoisoned ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_mapping.h:295
        #1 0x7f891c950e26 in QuickCheckForUnpoisonedRegion ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:40
        #2 0x7f891c950e26 in __interceptor_memset ../../.././libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:451
        #3 0x7f8918453dad in cmd_passthru /home/usr2/git/tmp2/qat_crypto.c:126
...
```

How should I do to skip check this function? Or is there any other way to find the cause of segment fault?

Comment: How do you know that the line is not an error?

Comment: That memory address is a virtual address that mapped through ioctl by remap_pfn_range in kernel module. So it's a specific address I determined, and I print the address in gdb, and it's expected value.

Comment: A SEGFAULT is often the visible symptom of Undefined Behaviour invoked *anywhere* in the program... That is the reason why UB is the hell of C programmers: if some code contains UB, it may succeed in tests and later break the program at any point. Maybe you should twice control any left warning, all memory allocations/de-allocations, and all array sizes for the beginning...